# How clear the form inputs after submission?

Tags: javascript, html

Already tried everything from different references but, I can't get it to work. I intended to use it for google photo submission form. I just want my text inputs and textarea to clear after it successfully uploaded everything.

Here's the whole HTML code.

```html
<form id="uploaderForm">
        <label for="uploaderForm">Photo Upload Form</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="applicantName" id="applicantName"
                placeholder="Your Name">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="gradesection" id="gradesection"
                placeholder="Your Grade Level & Section">
        </div><br>
        <div>
            You can select multiple Photos upload!<br>
            <br>
            <input type="file" name="filesToUpload" id="filesToUpload" multiple>
            <br><br>
            <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="uploadFiles()"> 
        </div>
    </form>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <script>
        var rootFolderId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        var numUploads = {};
        numUploads.done = 0;
        numUploads.total = 0;
        // Upload the files into a folder in drive
        // This is set to send them all to one folder (specificed in the .gs file)
        function uploadFiles() {
            var allFiles = document.getElementById('filesToUpload').files;
            var applicantName = document.getElementById('applicantName').value;
            if (!applicantName) {
                window.alert('Missing applicant name!');
            }
            var gradesection = document.getElementById('gradesection').value;
            if (!gradesection) {
                window.alert('Missing Grade & Section!');
            }
            var folderName = applicantName + ' - ' + gradesection;
            if (allFiles.length == 0) {
                window.alert('No file selected!');
            } else {
                numUploads.total = allFiles.length;
                google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(r) {
                    // send files after the folder is created...
                    for (var i = 0; i < allFiles.length; i++) {
                        // Send each file at a time
                        uploadFile(allFiles[i], r.folderId);
                    }
                }).createFolder(rootFolderId, folderName);
            }
        }

        function uploadFile(file, folderId) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                var content = reader.result;
                document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'uploading '
                        + file.name + '...';
                //window.alert('uploading ' + file.name + '...');               
                google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onFileUploaded)
                        .uploadFile(content, file.name, folderId);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }

        function onFileUploaded(r) {
            numUploads.done++;
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'uploaded '
                    + r.fileName + ' (' + numUploads.done + '/'
                    + numUploads.total + ' files).';
            if (numUploads.done == numUploads.total) {
                document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'All of the '
                        + numUploads.total + ' files are uploaded';
                numUploads.done = 0;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

The form upload and displays the response to the user.

I want to reset the form so, the form resets to its original state, so when the user upload another file  it wont upload the same file again. Right now, the submission message stays and I have no clue on how to reset the form.

I am new to javascript and I have no clue on what to call to rest the form, any idea? TIA Guys :)

Comment: do you want to reset the input type file?

Comment: Hi thanks.  I want to reset the whole form including the confirmation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your code snippet only contains `input`, You can find all inputs using `querySelectorAll` and reset its `value`.

Example below. When you click the button it resets all the input.

```js
function resetAllInput() {
    const allInput = document.querySelectorAll('input');
    allInput.forEach( input => {
        input.value = "";
    })
}

function uploadFiles() {
    console.log('uploading files');
    resetAllInput();
  console.log('Resetted all inputs');
}
```

```html
<form id="uploaderForm">
        <label for="uploaderForm">Photo Upload Form</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="applicantName" id="applicantName" placeholder="Your Name">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="gradesection" id="gradesection" placeholder="Your Grade Level & Section">
        </div><br>
        <div>
            You can select multiple Photos upload!<br>
            <br>
            <input type="file" name="filesToUpload" id="filesToUpload" multiple>
            <br><br>
            <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="uploadFiles()">
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: I can't get it to work.  it reset everything before the confirmation of upload

Comment: You’ve to call the reset function after the confirmation

Answer (score 0):

You can assign null value to your input element:

```js
const reset = () => {
  let fileInput = document.getElementById('file-input');
  fileInput.value = null;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file-input">
<button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I implement this after the javascript upload confirmation?

Comment: you can call the reset() function at the bottom of uploadFile() function